# TFS Builds using Eclipse CDT from Debian Box

Tags: c++, boost, debian, eclipse-cdt, tfsbuild

I would like to use TFS Build system from Debian OS, I develop using C++, my IDE is Eclipse CDT. I would like to know if using TFS Build System is possible, if so how? as a side note, My development heavily relies on Boost libraries and QT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. You cannot run TFS builds on Linux. However you can use TFS build to run ANT or Maven, which in turn can be used to build c++.

The build will run on a TFS build agent, which will be a windows machine. Usually a different machine to the TFS server. This can be a VM, your TFS gurus should be able to set this up for you.

To use ANT or Maven you need the [TFS build extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45b4e378-5b81-4186-9b7f-21cc5c2f743d) the link is for the TFS 2012 version, however there are extensions for older versions of TFS.

Once you have a build server set up you can use [ANT to build your c++ code](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ant%20c%2b%2b%20build&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari) or [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541771/using-maven-for-c-c-projects).

If I was going to attempt this, I would get the ANT build working on a windows box first, then plumb it in to TFS with the extensions.

However, you might be better off using a more generic build engine such as [Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653372/buildbot-vs-hudson-jenkins-for-c-continuous-integration), running on Linux which [connects to TFS](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Team+Foundation+Server+Plugin) to retrieve the code.